# How to deploy a Firebase Function (2nd gen) to multiple regions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

With Gen1 functions it was easy to deploy to multiple regions, but I can't see how to do it for Gen2 functions.

How do I select multiple regions to deploy this to?

```
setGlobalOptions({ region: "northamerica-northeast1" });
exports.myFunction = onRequest({
    minInstances: 2,
    memory: "1GiB",
    concurrency: 80,
    cors: true
},
    (async (req, res) => {
});
```

I have tried:

```
setGlobalOptions({ region: "northamerica-northeast1", "northamerica-northeast2" });
```

It doesn't work, when you try and deploy you get the error:
**HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied on 'locations/northamerica-northeast1, northamerica-northeast2' (or it may not exist).**

I can successfully deploy to 1 region with a Gen2 function, but not to multiple. Any ideas?

### Update: here is the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76773958/3890041

Comment: Have you checked this [Best practices for changing region](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#best_practices_for_changing_region) 

**Note**: "You can specify multiple regions by passing multiple comma-separated region strings in functions.region(). See change a function's region for more information on recommended procedures."

Comment: @DominicT yes, that works for Gen1 functions, but how to do for Gen2? e.g. setGlobalOptions({ region: "northamerica-northeast1", "region2example" }); doesn't work.

Comment: That wouldn't work because it's syntactically incorrect javascript and would never compile.  Separate the names of the regions within the same string.

Comment: API docs for the [GlobalOptions.region](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptionsregion) property suggests that it only accepts one.  Maybe what you have here is a feature request.

Comment: @FlatDog You can try this [gist example](https://gist.github.com/Rohit1024/b29046bbedb7deeb0bd97c81aeb9c892) which will ask you the [SupportedRegion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.md#supportedregion) input while deploying it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I found out how to do it from Firebase Support, I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with Firebase support, you can do it by using the property "region" and putting into "[]" the regions where you want to deploy the function, like below:

```
setGlobalOptions({ region: ["northamerica-northeast1", "northamerica-northeast2"] });
exports.myFunction = onRequest({
```

Comment: Great Answer. For typescript folks out there use `setGlobalOptions({ region: ["northamerica-northeast1", "northamerica-northeast2"] as unknown as string });` to get out of  `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | Expression<string> | ResetValue | undefined'.` Error.